# .net mvc jquery to sql parameter

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an MVC web application in .net that has 2 drop down lists with a list of timestamps. I am able to populate those drop downs successfully using linq query from the model of IEnumerable<> (.edmx).

```
@model IEnumerable<Softwares>
@{ var times = from ts in Model select ts.Distinct() }

<select id="time1">
@foreach(var item in times)
  { <option> @item </option> }
</select>

<select id="time2">
@foreach(var item in times)
  { <option> @item </option> }
</select>


<button id="compare> Compare </button>
```

I need to take these 2 timestamps as parameters into an sql query. When debugging it seems that I am able to pass the timestamps back to the Action Result in my controller, into the model to as parameters and then back to my Controller.

```
<script> 
var t1 = $("#time1").val();
var t2 = $("#time2").val();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#compare").click(){
      $.post("Home/CompareSoftware", {time1 = t1, time2 = t2},
          function(data){
             alert(data)
        });
 </script>
```

My problem is getting the value from the controller and pushing it back to the view formatted as a table. I'm not quite sure what the "data" is because it seems like it is my t1 and t2 that I'm passing back to my Controller action CompareSoftware. I try just getting it to show up in an alert box but when I run this script and click compare I get an unsuccessful message. Please note that I am writing this code from memory so it might not be exactly correct here.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult CompareSoftware(string time1, string time2){

time1 = t1; time2 = t2; Convert to TimeStamp.

var retVal = Models.CompareSoftware(t1, t2)

return View(retVal) 
}
```

My model takes in 2 timestamps and returns a List class that has 4 fields. My code is paraphrased above but when debugging I am able to get a return value from my model and push it back to the Controller. How to I display this information to the view? I'm guessing this ajax post returns JSON data and I need to convert that to my view? I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your alert isn't showing data because you aren't referencing the individual item in the list. Add this to your JQuery

```
function(data){
   $.each(data, function (index, item) {
       alert(item);
   });
});
```

I'm assuming you're trying to return the results on the same page? If so try this:

**Controller:** return a Partial View

```
 return PartialView("YourPartialViewFolder/YourPartialView", Your_List);
```

**JQuery:** Returns the table to the Partial

```
 $.post("Home/CompareSoftware", {time1 = t1, time2 = t2},
      function(data){
         $('#PartialID').html(data)
    });
```

**Partial View** Here you would just have an empty table until it is clicked. So I would hide it, unless you want an empty table to show.

```
<table id="PartialID">
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <th>Header Title</th>
    </thead>
  </tr>
  @foreach(var item in Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <tbody>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ListItem)</td>
      </tbody>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Comment: Do I need to declare the model at the top of the view like I did for the drop down lists?

Comment: Yea you do so it would be `@models yourNameSpace.FolderName.ModelName`

Comment: Im new to asp.net mvc so im wondering how the Jquery you added will know to post the data to #PartialID when it's in a different view. Also wouldn't I declare my model as @model IList <namespace.modelfolder.model>?

Comment: Also my model is performing a method that takes in the 2 timestamps so do I call the method at the end of the model call in the view?  I see that you can do @renderpartial ("~/partialviewlocation", what do I put here)   my model returns a list of another model class with the 4 fields so which one do I want to return

Comment: You need to reference the partial view on your view `     @Html.Partial("~/Path/to/PartialView/Partial.cshtml", Model.Parts)` . This will add the contents of your partial to your view, making them one view.